# Mesmo conjunto de dados, duas rectas, duas equações, no mesmo gráfico?

Tags: python, r, microsoft-excel

Os meus dados ajustam-se facilmente por uma recta, mas ainda melhor com 2, dividindo os dados. 
Preciso de dividir os dados em 2 partes, assim: concentrações (x) até 700 ppm e concentrações > ou = 700 ppm. E posso ter de mudar este 700, como a fronteira entre rectas.

Qual é a forma mais simples de conseguir ter um gráfico em que mostra duas rectas lineares e respectivas equações e R^2 ?

EDIT:
Estou a tentar desenvolver a solução com o R (aceito outras formas).

Criei um subset dos meus dados <700 e estou a ajustar um modelo linear aqui.

Comment: Bem-vinda ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: É Python, R ou Excel?

Comment: Na verdade, é o que conseguir resolver o problema. Estou mais à vontade com o R, mas entendo-me em Python. Obrigada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para traçar duas linhas de regressão, tem primeiro que criar uma variável extra, que diga a que parte pertence cada grupo de dados, se `x < 700`, se `x >= 700`.

```
library(ggplot2)


df$group <- factor(as.integer(df$x < 700))

ggplot(df, aes(x = z, y = x, colour = group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Dados.**

Este código serve para criar um conjunto de dados fictício.

```
set.seed(1234)    # Torna os resultados reprodutíveis

n <- 100
x1 <- runif(n, 0, 700)
x2 <- runif(n, 700, 1400)
x <- 0.75*x1 + 2 + rnorm(n, sd = 16)
x <- c(x, 2*x2 + 1 + rnorm(n, sd = 25))
df <- data.frame(x, z = c(x1, x2))
```

Comment: E como fazer para ter as respectivas equações e R^2 a aparecerem?